# Blender IK Constraint Location Offset?

Tags: armature, bones, transforms, constraints

I may not know all the correct terminology for this, but I'll try my best to make it understandable. I also don't know if this has already been answered elsewhere, because I don't know how I'd go about searching for it.

I'm having an issue with IK constraints involving location. I'm trying to constrain the left hand to the right hand (on the same armature) and it works well, however the left hand automatically snaps to the origin of the right hand's bone, as pictured here.
[image: rig with IK constraints]

I need to offset the position of the left hand back to where it was previously, before I added the modifier [perhaps somewhat similar to the way child constraint's "set inverse" option works].  Is this possible?

Comment: Can you upload your file?

Comment: @Fuboski I'm not sure if there's a specific way to do it, but does this suffice? [https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/215505034/carbinetest.blend](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/215505034/carbinetest.blend)

Comment: listen what do you want to achieve? Two arms that can move exactly at the same way using only one of them ( the second will copy all the positions)?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to make it so the left-hand stays attached to the right hand, but I don't want them to be physically right next to each other, like in the screenshot. When I add an IK modifier, the left-hand bone snaps to the right-hand bone and stays there, but I need to move it elsewhere to make it look as if it's gripping a gun.

Comment: oki understand ;) let's me work and i'll give you a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the file:

[image]

[image]

I simply did these steps:

1) In your Hand.L **I delete the Copy Location** (it's useless) and **delete your IK constraint connected with the bone Hand.R**

2) **I create a new bone**(the one in the immagine called CHILD), named BONETARGET.L (no deform), and **i set this bone near to the position where i would like to have my Hand.L**, hanging my weapon.

3) **I create a constraint between "body"** (there is a bone you called body) **and BONETARGET.L**; theh my BONETARGET is the child of body

[image]

4) **I create an IK contraint between my BONETARGET and the Hand.L**; then my Hand.L has the BONETARGET like the target for its IK

[image]

In other words i have created a chain,

- you move the Hand.R that moves in the same way the "body"
- the BONETARGET.L will move like the "body", and at the same time will be the target for your IK left arm that will move following this bone (BONETARGET.L)

In the end I add other 2 things:

[image]

4) I tick "Perserve volume" to mantain the volume of your mesh while you are animating, and i add a modifier (**PS this one is available from the last blender verison, 2.77**) called Corrective Smooth. It helps a lot and keep the mesh clear from strange and tricky deformation.

Tell me if this is the solution you were searching

Comment: This is not quite what I was looking for. I'm trying to make it look as though the right hand is gripping a gun, and the example you provided looks as though the left arm simply mirrors the right arm. I need the left arm to move like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/215505034/ShareX/2016/04/2016-04-07_20-28-14.gif), but I also need to pose the left arm to make it grip the gun, like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/215505034/ShareX/2016/04/blender-app_2016-04-07_20-30-55.png).

Comment: Ok i understand, I edit my answer!

Comment: Glad to help you! Have a nice day ;)